# Is there a way to code this with an if else statement and get a similar result?

Tags: python

1. Is there a way to code this with an if else statement and get a similar result (MENU display part) ?

print ("A. Snack 1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - $1.80: {}".format( "Available" if amount >= item_a and stock_a > 0 else "Insufficient coins" if stock_a > 0 else "Sold out"))

Need to check if coin insert is sufficient if not display insufficient coins and also check if there are stock.

2. print("Current amount: ${}".format("%.2f" % (amount / 100)))
   Is there other way to print the current amount without using the {} ?
3. print("Selection {} not on menu.".format(insert.upper()))
   Is there other way to print this without using the {} ?
4. What do I enter to try out if the chance of being stuck is working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking us to do a code review or code check for you?

Comment: @JosipJuros review :)

Comment: You can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running python3, you can do

`print(f"Selection {insert.upper()} not on menu.")`
instead of
`print("Selection {} not on menu.".format(insert.upper()))`

Code reviews aren't really part of this website I don't think, but I hope that the printing command helps you out